# HighCharts - Zoom View Resets

Tags: ios, highcharts, zooming, pinchzoom

We are building an iOS app using HighCharts components. Defined HIColumn for Bar Chart in XAxis with couple of HISpline (AreaChart) overlay on yAxis that can be toggled. When a user is zoomed in to a specific xAxis period, upon adding the spline, the Chart looses the Zoom and redraw itself. Is it possible to add a spline at runtime without loosing the zoom? These are the things I tried:

1. Set Min/Max on XAxis. How can we get the current Min/Max/tickInterval when the user zoom in on the xAxis.
2. Instead of dynamically adding the spline, tried making it visible true/false but still the chart refresh and lose the zoom.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Colud you provide some minimal live working demo of this issue (jsfiddle ideally)?